# How did Newton support himself during his research?

Tags: science, early-modern

It is said that Isaac Newton, at the age of 23, came home and made his famous discoveries. Who sponsored him? Or did he farm while doing his research?

Comment: If I remember correctly, he did a lot of his major stuff during the Plague, where he was in his castle avoiding everyone so he didn't get sick. In short, I don't think he did ANYTHING but develop the Calculus.

Comment: it's an excellent question. he wasn't rich. he got scholarship while in Cambridge, and did valet before it. so he clearly needed some income to survive during the plague 2 years.

Comment: @jinawee - Perhaps I'm being dense, but I don't see the answer in there.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace We can't mark it duplicate because then, it will say, _This question is duplicate and already has an answer here..._. But it has no answer anywhere. Anyway, he was certainly from a rich family. At least better than other better scientists.

Comment: Then perhaps we should just close/delete the question?